# Viewing memory allocations in C# and Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, garbage-collection

I'm trying to pinpoint the cause of high GC use in an Asp.net 4.6 web site.  I've isolated a large routine that seems to be allocating a lot of memory from the heap.  The problem is that the GC kicks in at the end of the routine (or immediately afterwards) and cleans up the heap.  The routine takes only 1-2 seconds to run so taking a "Heap snapshot" isn't quick enough.

Is it possible to somehow log or view allocations even though they were eventually garbage collected?

Answer (score 0):

You might try the performance wizard that comes with VS. It has an option to  track .NET Memory Allocation.

On VS 2012 you would go to: Analyze > Performance Wizard (I'm not sure what it is for VS 2015, but is probably similar). Navigating to that opens a pop-up and then select the option, ".NET Memory Allocation (sampling)". That might give you what you need. Otherwise, there are 3rd party memory profilers as well from companies like RedGate that can track managed memory allocation.